# Strange results in bitwise program in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

writing the code below give me strange answers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char a=0x03 ,b=0x01 ,x;

    printf("Enter two numbers : \n");
    scanf("%c %c",&a,&b);
    printf("0x%x 0x%x\n",a,b);
    printf("0x%x || 0x%x = 0x%x \n0x%x ^ 0x%x = 0x%x\n0x%x << 0x%x = 0x%x\n0x%x >> 0x%x = 0x%x\n",a,b,a||b,a,b,a^b,a,b,a<<b,a,b,a>>b);
    scanf("%i",x);

    return 0;
}
```

this gives me the following results

```
Enter two numbers :
2 3
32 33 
0x32 || 0x33 = 0x1
0x32 ^ 0x33 = 0x1
0x32 << 0x33 = 0x1900000
0x32 >> 0x33 = 0x0
```

I don't know why it does  take wrong value into a and b 
although I've tried it using int and it worked well ?!

Comment: `scanf("%i",x);`  ??? working????

Comment: yeah if the type is of type int

Comment: `scanf("%i", address)`, so it can't work... it will cause an "access" to memory you likely can't access to

Comment: `yeah if the type is of type int ` ok then, happy segfault in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking input as `char` and printing as `int`. That's why you see the difference.

When you take `2` and `3` as `char`, they are stored as ASCII value of these numbers which are `0x32` and `0x33` (or `50` and `51` in decimal). When you print them as integer, you read these bytes as integer, which explains your  output.

Also, the `||` operator you have used is not a `bitwise OR`, it is a `Logical OR`. A logical OR can only produce `1` or `0` depending on operand values are zero or non-zero. Instead, Bitwise OR does a bit-by-bit OR of each bit of the variable, which you probably want.

**UPDATE:** (Answer to your question in comment)

1) To print them as character, you need to convert the integer number into `char` string. I will give you a hint:

```
Character        Corresponding ASCII Value(decimal)

   '0'                      48
   '1'                      49
   '2'                      50
 ...
   '9'                      57
```

2) To print them as hexadecimal, since you have already scanned them as `int` just use `%x`. (`%hhx` on Linux)

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I print them as character and hexadecimal at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%c %c",&a,&b);
```

Look in the documentation for `scanf()` and see what `%c` is supposed to be. You'll find that it's not an integer. So even though you enter `2` and `3`, the format specifier treats this in an unexpected way in your case. Once you understand what `%c` is then, the rest will be clear.

Comment: so I can't read a number using %c, is it must be %i?
cause I learned that a character may be used in short numbers

Comment: @Salahuddin, correct, you must use `%i` format specifier to indicate that you are reading a number and *not a character*

Comment: @Salahuddin : If you are on Linux, you can use `%hhu` or `%hhd` depending on you want `unsigned` or `signed` integer value.